# How to check whether or not a dynamic property exists

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtcore, qobject

I have use `setProperty` function to set dynamic property to object.
But I want in other place to check if the property that was created is exists or not.

**What I done:**
**When set the property:**

```
QString fileDlg = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this, "Open File", "F://","Text Files(*.txt)");
QWidget *widget = new QWidget(this);
QMdiSubWindow *mdiWindows = ui->mdiArea->addSubWindow(widget);
mdiWindows->setProperty("filePath", fileDlg);
```

**When check if property exists:**

```
QMdiSubWindow *activeWindow = ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow();
if(activeWindow->property("filePath") == true){
    // code here
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If the property doesn't exist, the `QObject::property` method returns an invalid variant. This is [documented](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qobject.html#property).

Thus:

```
QVariant filePath = activeWindow->property("filePath");
if (filePath.isValid()) {
  ...
}
```

Side note: comparing anything to `true` is either completely superfluous, or a sign of broken design somewhere. You should not have `... == true` nor `... == false` anywhere in your code.

Comment: I think your way is more simpler, and nearest to my code.

Comment: Oh well, and how to distunguish between unset property and property set to `QVariant()`?

Comment: There's no need to distinguish between them. If you think you need to, you need to use a custom data type and only wrap that in the variant.

Comment: @TomášZato An unset dynamic property is a null `QVariant`. A property that has been set will have some value, although the value itself may be null. E.g. say that we set the variant to `QString{}`. The `QVariant::isNull()` is false, but `QVariant::toString().isNull()` is true, because the variant was set with a string value that just happens to be null - the variant doesn't care about that though. From variant's viewpoint, it's either set and thus non-null, or unset and thus null. The enclosed data types may have their own "null/non-null" distinction, but it's optional.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are trying to check the QVariant property directly, whereas it is not even sure if it exists in your case.

I would personally use either of the solutions below depending on your exact context in the real program.

Replace the variable placeholder with your preferred property name if you wish.

```
QVariant myPropertyValue =
    ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->property(myPropertyName);
if(myPropertyValue.isValid())
    qDebug() << myPropertyName << "exists.";
```

or:

```
QList<QByteArray> dynamicPropertyNames =
    ui->mdiArea->activeSubWindow()->dynamicPropertyNames();
if (dynamicPropertyNames.contains(myPropertyName))
    qDebug() << myPropertyName << "exists.";
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm also benefited from your code.

Comment: @LionKing: nice, by the way, I was thinking about that while cycling home that you could probably also query the property directly and see if it exists that way. I updated the answer.